# How to make a CD with audio and data at the same time

Tags: audio, music

I made a homebrew game and want to distribute it to my friends using CD's. The game uses CD Audio music and I already made a quick program to check if the disc is in the drive, but I don't know how to make a CD with audio and data and the same time. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but the terms you're looking for is "mixed mode cd". Maybe that will help you find [ways to do it](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+make+mixed+mode+cd).

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Do you have any specific restrictions or preferences on how you want this encoded? For instance, is it okay if the data appears (as a possibly unplayable) audio track?

Comment: @Pikalek yep, I have no problem with that, I just want the music to work in a computer, and not top priority to be also possible to play in a car radio or cd player. I've done some research on the orange book format and on newer players it would detect that it's data and skip it but if it does not work like that I still wouldn't mind.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I searched for it and found a program called CDBurnerXP and a tutorial on it's site, will that work?

Comment: I don't know :) You try and tell us!